# Resizing image with exact width and height in php

Tags: php, image, resize

I am sure this topic has been discussed number of times and I have started doing this from yesterday evening but till now no complete satisfaction.I am using the following code and it gives me a resized image but the scaling is not correct.The height and width is not in it's correct proportion.

I couldn't find any good fiddle like jsfiddle where you can see the output so pasting my code here.

You can see the original image url here also I have attached a resized image.

http://distilleryimage4.s3.amazonaws.com/b1da08e4484511e38e4d0a7011810191_7.jpg

```
$filename = 'http://distilleryimage4.s3.amazonaws.com/b1da08e4484511e38e4d0a7011810191_7.jpg';
//the resize will be a percent of the original size
$percent = 0.589;
$percent_height = 0.294;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent_height;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);


imagejpeg($thumb);
imagedestroy($thumb);
```

[image: Resized Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a Math problem:

You are scaling width and height to both different proportions (`$percent` and `$percent_height`). You should scale both of them (width and height) by the same percent, to get an image resized to the same ratio. Maybe I didn't understand your question but I think you should change this line:

```
$newheight = $height * $percent_height;
```

to

```
$newheight = $height * $percent;
```

(and remove `$percent_height = 0.294;` if we are not gonna use it here)

Comment: Many Thanks for your suggestion.It worked.I did that and it gives me perfect scaling.Is there any way where I can mention a fixed height and width to the image.

Comment: Yes, but when the image hasn't got the same width and height (not squared, but rectangular) it gets complicated. I guess you are down-scaling. There is a function I use to reduce pictures bigger than 1024 x 786: http://pastebin.com/kWQE0PTK `$maxW` and `$maxH` are the desired maximum sizes, change them to whatever you need. Pass the file path as the only argument to the function. It will return an array containing the original `width`,`height`, and the calculated ones. Hope you learn from it

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Imagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php). I was doing resizing with `imagecreatetruecolor`, but it takes a lot of time (0,5 seconds) to resize 1920*1080 image to 150*120.

If you still want to use imagecreatetruecolor: to get the correct scalling use [this code](http://chrisltd.com/blog/2013/07/php-proportional-image-resizing-math/).

Comment: Or you can use external class: [link](https://github.com/eventviva/php-image-resize)